# How to install XUnit VisualStudio Runner once per station

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xunit

**EDITED:**
In order to use `xUnit VisualStudio Runner` it's required to install it as `Nuget package`. This approach is problematic due (1) user's obligation to add this package to *every* project that it's creating and (2) problem with references to the package binaries.

(1) It seems unimportant, but the requirement to add a package to every project is another manual operation that user has to do which is unnecessary overhead that we're looking to remove.

(2) Our product (unfortunately) doesn't maintain constant solution hierarchy. As result, everyone creates custom suited solutions. As result, the `packages` folder location changes depending on the location of the solution file. It in turn reflects the path which is hard-coded into project file (.csproj) about the location of the `xUnit VisualStudio Runner` package which makes impossible managing the code (each user is enforced to alter the project file during his work).

We're looking for a way to register the `xUnit VisualStudio Runner` binaries as a unit test runner without using Nuget package registration process.

I'll appreciate any hints on the subject. I found no way to ask xUnit developers this question. I've reviewed the way it's done officially [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2012/07/31/writing-a-visual-studio-2012-unit-test-adapter/) and [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bhuvaneshwari/2012/03/13/authoring-a-new-visual-studio-unit-test-adapter/).
The [VS extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/463c5987-f82b-46c8-a97e-b1cde42b9099) that does the job is claimed to be obsolete and cannot be installed on VS anymore.

Thank you.

Comment: You cannot. Accept the new design or switch to another framework.

Comment: Do you have any information to support this statement?

Comment: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/463c5987-f82b-46c8-a97e-b1cde42b9099 Simply read what is in bold.

Comment: Your reference is to what xUnit team stated regarding their extension package. I'm not looking to revive the extension. I'm looking to take the package and (for example) place them somewhere in such a way that VS will pick them up _always_ and not only when they're part of the project. Any other solution will do that let me install once and use for all projects.

Comment: the NuGet package is restored only once per solution, so VS does reuse the binaries efficiently in a way it can support. I don't get what you want so you'd better make it clearer and update your question.

Comment: The question is changed. Doesn't help to answer it though...

Comment: Xunit is open source on GitHub. Find the repo and fire an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to create VS extension for VS2015 that uses XUnit Nuget package. The extension installs binaries of the package as UnitTest adapter. You can find a package in [xunit-vs-adapter](https://github.com/minherz/xunit-vs-adapter). Note that it uses a specific version of the XUnit adapter. I didn't do dynamic upload of the most recent version.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of distributing the NuGet Adapter as a Vsix you can create a Company Unit Test Project Template which includes the NuGet reference. If you want to take it even further you could upload these project templates as extensions to a private extension gallery.

Users creating new test projects will automatically include the right NuGet package and you won't need to have every user install the VSIX.

See also

- [How to: Create a Project Template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xkh1wxd8.aspx)
- [How to: Create a SideWaffle Template Pack](https://github.com/ligershark/side-waffle/wiki/How-to-create-your-own-template-pack)

You can [use MyGet to easily host a private Extension gallery](http://www.myget.org), or download one of [the free open-source solutions](https://inmetavsgallery.codeplex.com/).

### Background

A little background on why this is important:

- By not including the NuGet package in the solution the CI server (TFS Build for example) will need to have a matching version of the runner installed, otherwise there can be compatibility issues between the developer workstation and the build server.
- If the build server has a specific version of the runner installed, it will be hard to migrate to a new version of XUnit when there are breaking changes in the runner (NUnit 3 for example has incompatibilities with 2.6). You'll either have to stick to the old framework or upgrade all solutions at once or spin up a new build server for the new solutions.
- It won't allow a developer to work on an older solution (referencing an older version of XUnit) while also working on a fresh solution which may be targeting the most recent version of XUnit.

Creating a Project Template is very easy, especially if you're using SideWaffle. And distributing that will allow you to help your developers with fewer steps, yet gives you the freedom of decoupling your solutions from your workstation configuration.

Comment: Thank you. I've explained why using Nuget packages is a problem in our development environment, especially a package to be used as Unit test adapter. Please, see the question body for more details. Same about "not including package into solution".
In commercial product environments like ours we don't upgrade packages (commercial or open source) too often. Thus, we don't have a problem working with a fixed version of XUnit package.
Personally, I don't like to use a package in order to create a package to solve the problem. Simpler -- better!